# dc.js not displaying the y-axis

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a set of data that i would like to render on a line chart for the frequency

Data Parsing

```
var volumeChart = dc.barChart('#monthly-volume-chart');
var dateFormatSpecifier = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z';
    var dateFormat = d3.timeFormat(dateFormatSpecifier);
    var dateFormatParser = d3.timeParse(dateFormatSpecifier);
    var numberFormat = d3.format('.2f');

    data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.dd = dateFormatParser(d.timestamp);
        d.minute = d3.timeMinute(d.dd)
        //coerce to number with a +
    });
```

Dimension grouping

```
var freqByMins = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.minute;
});
var aa = freqByMins.group()
console.log(aa.all())
var freqByMinsGroup = aa.reduceCount(function (d) {
    return d.minute;
});
console.log(freqByMinsGroup.all())
```

Looking at `freqByMinsGroup.all()` i get the following data

```
0: {key: Thu Feb 21 2019 05:29:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time), value: 2}
1: {key: Thu Feb 21 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time), value: 5}
2: {key: Thu Feb 21 2019 05:31:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time), value: 6}
3: {key: Thu Feb 21 2019 05:32:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time), value: 3}
4: {key: Thu Feb 21 2019 05:33:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time), value: 1}
5: {key: Thu Feb 21 2019 05:34:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time), value: 1}
6: {key: Thu Feb 21 2019 05:35:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time), value: 3}
7: {key: Thu Feb 21 2019 05:36:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time), value: 4}
8: {key: Thu Feb 21 2019 05:38:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time), value: 4}
9: {key: Thu Feb 21 2019 05:39:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time), value: 7}
length: 10
```

Rendering charts

```
 volumeChart.width(960)
    .height(100)
    .margins({top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40})
    .dimension(freqByMins)
    .group(freqByMinsGroup)
    .transitionDuration(500)
    .elasticY(true)

    .x(d3.scaleTime().domain([new Date(2019, 2, 21, 5, 29, 0), new Date(2019, 2, 21, 5, 40, 0)]))
    .xAxis();
```

However, my crossfilter chart does not render any y-axis.

Attached is an image

[image]

Comment: Again, it's still not enough info to reproduce the problem. When I put your code in a fiddle in the other question, it showed the Y axis. Could you please try forking [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/ckf3d2cv/) and adding your code?

Comment: @Gordon, i resolved it already. It was an error on my end with the html. I given my correction in the answer below. Thanks for helping. I couldnt do a jsfiddle as i cannot seem to be able to find dc.js in it

Comment: Awesome, thanks for following up. My guess is some errant CSS since I can't see the problem either.

Comment: @Gordon it’s the same example as ur stock.js in dc.datatables.js. I was jacking around with that. I didn’t change any css. And your demo also had the same problem so I was assuming it’s expected behavior?

Comment: Ah, it's intentionally hidden in the CSS because that makes it look nicer when used as a range chart, [see here](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/index.html#L13).

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

To anyone who might be looking at this question,

The error appeared in the html.

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="monthly-move-chart">
        <strong>Monthly Index Abs Move & Volume/500,000 Chart</strong>
        <span class="reset" style="display: none;">range: <span class="filter"></span></span>
        <a class="reset" href="javascript:moveChart.filterAll();volumeChart.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();"
           style="display: none;">reset</a>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When i used another index with

```
<div id="quarter-chart">
        <strong>Quarters</strong>
        <a class="reset" href="javascript:quarterChart.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();" style="display: none;">reset</a>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
```

It worked. I am guessing that this is because it had a dependency on another chart. I was literally hacking around with the example from https://dc-js.github.io/dc.datatables.js/ which might result in some funny errors when i didnt really check the html